# Carbon - Check one month to go, one week to go etc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I have a list of members on my website, and I have their membership start date and expiry date stored in my database as timestamps. Now I want to send them emails

- one month before membership expiry date
- one week before membership expiry date
- one day before membership expiry date

How can I determine if there is one month/week/day is left in expiry based on stored expiry date?

The project is done in Laravel 4.2, and I am using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for all the details.

```
 $now = Carbon::now();
 $week = Carbon::now()->addWeek();
 $month=Carbon::now()->addMonth();
```

if `expiry_date` is the stored expiry date and Member is the model, using eloquent, this will give all the members expiring in one week.

```
$members=Member::where("expiry_date","<", $week)->get();
```

Comment: Do I have to fetch array of members from database, then do these date calculations on this array and send emails accordingly? Or is there a way to fetch results from database whose expiry date falls under this month, or this week etc?